# Move mouse out of bounds Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

My problem is really simple
I´ve an artifact with a mouse inside. When you use it it simulates moving the mouse cursor indefinitely to the right.
Of course when i run my project at some point the mouse will reach the right side of the movieclip and the Mouse_Move event wont work anymore
I need a way make my actionscript to recongnise mouse movement even if im out of bounds
(It´s a mobile aplication so using full screen wont work)

In other words i need a Mouse-Motion Listener!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is not possible to track mouse movements outside of flash with only ActionScript, you could capture the mouse position with javascript in the browser and pass it to your SWF.
See this blog as an example. http://www.nelsond8.com/?p=515

Comment: I´ve found the right words for what i need: a Mouse-Motion Listener!
How could i biud one in actionscript 3?

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** track the mouse position or actions when it moves outside of the stage.

You *can* however track when the mouse actually leaves the stage using [`Event.MOUSE_LEAVE`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/navigator/9/Navigator_SDK9_HTMLHelp/API_References/Acrobat_Navigator_API_Reference/flash/events/Event.html#MOUSE_LEAVE):

```
function mouseLeave(e:Event):void
{
    trace("Mouse left the stage.");
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeave);
```

From here you can decide what the most appropriate course of action will be for your application - adding some 'pause' functionality is pretty common.

Tip: `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` is what you should use to detect when the mouse re-enters the stage.

Comment: The thing is that the mouse movemets trigers the movieclip 
i want the movieclip to play endlesly even after the mouse is out of bounds
also the mouse movement speed afects how fast the movie plays

Comment: @JuanCarlosAllendeMena That's a nice idea but unfortunately you can't. Maybe in the `MOUSE_LEAVE` handler you can store the speed that the mouse was moving last and continue playing the MovieClip at that speed until the mouse returns?